# persisted data changed after rest service return

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jta

I have a REST service that use a stateless bean to perform an algorithm by using other beans.
All those beans made changes to the fields of my data, including a ManyToOne field.
At the end of the algorithm, just before the “return” of my rest service, my data is in the correct state, and the ManyToOne field in question has been changed.
But just after the return of the rest service, an update seems to happen on that field, and change it back to its previous state. But the other fields are still in the correct state.

What could possibly change my data after the “return” of my rest service ?

The project work with hibernate and JTA transactions in a wildfly environment.

The data looks like below :

```
public class Data extends JpaDecorator {
    @Column(length=1024)
    @Override
    public String getCommentaire() {
        return getImpl().getCommentaire();
    }

    @Column(length=1024)
    @Override
    public void setCommentaire(String value) {
        getImpl().setCommentaire(value);
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class JpaDecorator<T> {

    private WorkspaceJpa workspaceJpa;

    private T impl;

    @Transient
    public T getImpl() {
        return impl;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "wid", referencedColumnName = "oid")
    public WorkspaceJpa getJpaWid() {
        return this.workspaceJpa;
    }

    public void setJpaWid(WorkspaceJpa value) {
        this.workspaceJpa = value;

        Workspace wks = ((this.workspaceJpa != null) ? this.workspaceJpa.getImpl() : null);
        getImpl().setWid(wks);
    }

}
```

EDIT : 
I finally solved the problem. It came from an unclosed transaction used to collect the data at the beginning of the algorithm. That transaction stayed alive until the return of the rest service, and then was forced to end and flush the state of its data, which was obsolete.

Comment: Seems like transaction rolledback, can you share any pojo code code which is related with transaction? "my data is in the correct state" : in DB or its a debug observation from your app?
What is DB isolation level?

Comment: I doubt it is a rollback, I've no exception as usual and all other fields stay updated. I visualize the state of the fields directly with PGAdmin, so values seems to be updated in DB. What is "DB isolation level"? I will try do illustrate my code back at work, but I can't publish it "as is".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Comment: We use the postgres default isolation level, "read committed". I updated my question with a sample of my data, but I can't post all the code modifying its field, because it's separated all over thousands lines of code in 3 or more beans imbrication level